# 403 and CORS error accessing tomcat login page

Tags: java, jsp, intellij-idea, cors, tomcat7

I'm using tomcat web server with IntelliJ. I'm not sure what I have changed, but I can no longer hit my login jsp page. Here is output in chrome.

> VM5506:1 OPTIONS http://localhost:8105/api/login.jsp 403 (Forbidden)
>   (index):1 Failed to load http://localhost:8105/api/login.jsp: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:1841' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

The page has CORS header set on it:

```
<%
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Application, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
%>
```

I also tried setting the cors settings in the root web.xml in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\conf\web.xml

I am setting the "Origin" header correctly in the ajax request.

I can hit the page without doing a CORS request, e.g using curl.

The problem appears to be at the Tomcat level as debugging doesn't even reach the login page. I have tried setting cors config in the WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml:

```
 <filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
            <param-value>10</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
```

Same error.

I'm able to make the request if I switch off chrome security - but this is not the solution I want.

Thanks,
Av

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with the GET request itself - it's with the 'preflight' OPTIONS request that CORS is doing before it performs the actual GET.

Since you're getting a 403 response code for the OPTIONS request, I suspect your Tomcat web server simply doesn't allow OPTIONS requests at all. So check that first.

However, even if your Tomcat web server **does** allow OPTIONS requests, you'll still need to include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other CORS response headers in the response to the preflight OPTIONS request. I **think** your web.xml file has that correctly set up.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but no - I checked the config there are no restrictions. I can issue an OPTIONS request successfully via powershell.

Comment: Can you add the request/response headers for the OPTIONS request?

Comment: I tried capturing with fiddler, but it doesn't intercept OPTIONS request from powershell, can't show much. I'm going to try again tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing tomcat to fix the problem.